# Create refreshable Excel spreadsheet from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, report

I'm making an Excel report using 3 SQL Server queries one of which selects into a temp table and I want the result of these select statements into an Excel table.  I am new to Excel what is a good way to display the query result as a table and be able to refresh the table with new data from these 3 queries?  I've read about power query is this a good option?

my queries

```
Select into temp table 
join temp table with table 
join temp table with table 
union above 2 into 1 result table
```

Comment: Can this be useful for you? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-and-load-data-from-ms-sql-server-to-microsoft-excel/

Comment: SSRS will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Data->Get Data->From Database to load the SQL data into excel and the refresh button will update the table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Sub ImportFromSQLServer()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = "your_server_name"
Database_Name = "your_database_name"
'User_ID = "******"
'Password = "****"

SQLStr = "select distinct ID from mytable1"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"
'& ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

RS.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset RS
    End With

RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also, set a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library` (Tools > References).